# Find the force of the electric field on $(0,0)$ in the x-direction

Tags: integration

I think I get the general idea but I'm messing up the signs somehow, so the answer doesn't seem correct.

**Given:**

> $E=$magnitude of the electric field coming from an arc in the shape of a quarter circle with uniform charge density $\lambda$ in the 1st quadrant. The quarter circle has a radius of $r=1$.
>
> Find $E_x$, the magnitude of the force felt by the origin in the x-direction only.

**My attempt:**

Taking the positive x to be to the right and positive y to be up (so, a standard x-y axis), I get
$$-E_x=E\cos\theta$$
$$E_x=\int_0^{\pi /2} \cos \theta d\theta$$
$$E_x=E$$

The way I interpret this is that the origin feels the full force of the electric field, therefore there should be no force felt in the y-direction. But then that would make no sense. Each point on the arc has an x and a y component of force (except of course at $\theta = \pi /2$ and $\theta = 0$). I'm really confused...

Comment: What do you mean by "electric field coming from a quarter circle?"  Do you mean that there is a quarter circle of uniform charge density?

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry about that. I've edited the question.

Comment: Evaluating the integral gives you $\lambda/4\pi\epsilon_0$. The total electric field would just be $\sqrt{2}\lambda/4\pi\epsilon_0$. Why do you think your integral implies $E_x=E$?

Comment: Well, I was just keeping it in terms of $E$. So, $E_x=E=\frac{kq}{r^2}=k \lambda$.

Comment: What happens if you integrate from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ instead? By this logic, you'd get $E_x=2E$. $E$ is just the small contribution to the electric field from by an infinitesimal arc segment - it doesn't represent the entire electric field in any sense.

Comment: Ohhhhh yup, that's what I was confused about. I read $E$ thinking that it was the entire electric field because normally the total *anything* is written as a letter by itself (as in, without any subscripts or anything). But because we are only looking at an infinitesimal change in $\theta$, it must also be an infinitesimal change in the electric field, right?

Comment: More like, the electric field is proportional to the charge, which is equal to in this case to the arc-length $d\theta$ times the charge density $\lambda$. Each small piece of the arc $d\theta$ contributes $k\lambda d\theta/r^2$ to the electric field at the origin. We sum the small arc segments to find the total field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the $x-y$ plane, the electric field generated at the origin $(0,0)$ by an infinitesimal element of arc $dl=r d \theta$  is a vector of components:
$$
\mathbf{E}=\begin {bmatrix}
E_x\\E_y
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}
\begin {bmatrix}
\frac{\lambda dl}{r}\cos \theta\\\frac{\lambda dl}{r^2}\sin \theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}
\begin {bmatrix}
\frac{\lambda r d\theta}{r}\cos \theta\\\frac{\lambda r d\theta}{r^2}\sin \theta
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{\lambda}{4\pi r \epsilon_0}
\begin {bmatrix}
\cos \theta d\theta\\\sin \theta d \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so, for $r=1$, the total $x-$ component is:
$$
E_x=\frac{\lambda}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos \theta d \theta
$$

In the same way you can find the $y-$component, that obviously is not null.